# Difference between gets.chomp.to_i and gets.chomp in Ruby

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between `gets.chomp.to_i` and `gets.chomp` in Ruby? What does it do and how does it work?

Comment: It would help if you could explain which parts, *exactly*, of the documentation you do and don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

`gets` asks a user for some input and returns it exactly as it was entered. Notice that the returned value is a string and contains a newline at the end (since the user pressed the `Enter` key to submit their response):

```
> gets
> 1  # user input
=> "1\n"
```

Adding `chomp` removes the newline (technically, the record separator) from the input. Notice that `"1"` is now missing the newline at the end, but is still a string:

```
> gets.chomp
> 1  # user input
=> "1"
```

Adding `to_i` converts the input string into an integer. Notice that the return value is now an integer:

```
> gets.chomp.to_i
> 1  # user input
=> 1
```

Performing conversion with `.to_i` only make sense for integer inputs, as other string values will return 0:

```
> gets.chomp.to_i
> foo  # user input
=> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`gets` is used in scripts to retrieve user input. `.chomp` is used to remove newlines and carriage returns. See [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/chomp).

`gets.chomp` does return a string -> `to_i` converts the string to an integer.